# Apple-Touchpad randomly freezes

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad, synaptics, apple

This Problem occured first after a Software-Update last year:

A few hours after booting my System (an 2008 Macbook;running Ubuntu 16.04) my touchpad starts freezing randomly, unfreezing after a couple seconds or minutes. Restarting the appletouch driver via modprobe sometimes helps with getting the touchpad running again but the freezing will always persist.
Normally the freezes occur after releasing the touchpad.

Note that the suggested workarounds I've read up (disable tab-to-click; disable the “Disable touchpad while typing” option) made the freezes less frequent but they still occur.

I have seen this issue on 2 devices (same configuration)

```
xinput; dmesg | grep pnp; uname -r
```

returns me:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ appletouch                                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Apple Computer Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Apple Computer Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
[    0.267066] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.267848] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00    (active)
[    0.267889] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 4 devices
```

I configured my touchpad using the guidelines of following site:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook4-1/Raring

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I just installed Xubuntu on my early 2008 MacBook and I have the exact same thing.

Comment: I still have found no solution and normaly call sudo modprobe -r appletouch to have the touchpad working again.

Comment: Is this the same bug that is described here? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1834085 https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204589

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall xserver-xorg-xinput-all or reconfigure libpam-runtime do nothing in my case. And worst yet, my keyboard is also frozen along with the touchpad. My only option is the power button hard shutdown and it is a pain.
So I put these lines at the BEGINNING of /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh:

```
/sbin/shutdown -r now "Soft restart in case every thing failed"
exit
```

and when everything freeze, I simply push the power button.

Hope this help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo T480 Thinkpad. I regularly had Trackpad dropouts ever say five to fifteen minutes, exactly as the OP says.

I installed blueman, which adds a second bluetooth manager (on top of the one which comes with Ubuntu 18.04, which is probably standard gnome). When I have blueman running, I never have dropouts. The trackpad identifies in blueman as a "pointing" device, not as an HID Device.

Before this, I tried various configuration suggestions, but none worked.